# Disabling 'pulsate'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I temporarily disable the 'pulsate' jQuery  UI effect on a particular element? Such as this:

```
$('#player2,#score2').effect("pulsate", { times:5 }, 2000);
```

Comment: `$('#player2,#score2').stop(true,true);`

Comment: Just post it as an answer if you want so that I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop any animation that uses jQuery's FX queue you use :

`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`.

```
$('#player2,#score2').stop(true,true);
```

you will of course have to restart the animation again whenever .. !!